# Error Undefined offset 1 in al desencriptar con openssl linea 11

Tags: php

Intento desencryptar una contraseña y cuando la contraseña es correcta no muestra ni un error, y si la contraseña es incorrecta muestra esto:
Notice: Undefined offset 1 in C:.... on line 11

```
public static function decrypt($data, $key) {
    $encryption_key = base64_decode($key);
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($data), 2);// ESTA ES LA LINEA 11
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'RC4', $encryption_key, 0, $iv);
    }
```

Comment: porque en lugar de desencryptar no comparas los dos textos ya encriptados? osea encripta la clave que el usuario ingresa y comparala con la encriptada de la base de datos?

Comment: Ya lo eh echo y si me ah servido, pero tienes alguna idea de porque sucede esto?

Comment: Como te ha funcionado lo publicare como respuesta a la pregunta, y pues sinceramente no estoy muy seguro porque pasa esto, pero recuerdo que siempre me han recomendado comparar cadenas encryptadas en lugar de desencryptar la cadena a comparar

Comment: Ah decir verdad es mejor, porque al realizar un iniciar de cuenta, como al final es un WHERE en un SELECT asi sera mas rapido, luego con variables de session podrias tomar la clave que ingreso y cuando es correcta guardarla como la clave desencriptada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría en lugar de desencryptar la clave de la base de datos y compararla con la clave ingresada por el usuario, encryptar la clave ingresada por el usuario y comparar esa con la clave en la base de datos, termina siendo una mejor practica por motivos de seguridad, ya que la clave siempre permanece encryptada al momento de iniciar sesión